# Do you have to return after a http.Redirect if you want the code after to stop executing?

Tags: go

If I use http.Redirect in a middleware, do I explicitly have to return after the http.Redirect before calling next.ServeHTTP(w, r)?

If I have something like this, do I have to return explicitly after every http.Redirect in order for the code to stop executing after the redirect? What happens if I don't return?

```
// HTTPSNonWWWRedirect redirects http requests to https non www.
func HTTPSNonWWWRedirect(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if r.TLS == nil {
            u := *r.URL
            u.Scheme = "https"
            if r.Host[:3] == "www" {
                u.Host = r.Host[4:]
                http.Redirect(w, r, u.String(), http.StatusMovedPermanently)
                return
            }
            http.Redirect(w, r, u.String(), http.StatusMovedPermanently)
            return
        }
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

Comment: If you don't return it will keep executing, if you don't want to use the `return` keyword you can use the `else` branch in your `if` statements.

Comment: But I would still have to return after the else right? Or else it would go to the next handler.

Comment: If you do your `else` branches this way https://play.golang.org/p/wQAOpy5vjC, you can see the code stops where it should.

Comment: I understand. Thanks! May I ask which one you prefer? If with return or else?

Comment: Personally I'm not a fan of the `else` branch if the code inside its block is just one or two lines.. so in this specific case i would use `return` instead of `else`, and I also prefer to return early so as to avoid deep nested `if` statements. Something like this https://play.golang.org/p/uk0S1hCPhu but that's just me..

Comment: That was much better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http.Redirect` just redirects the user to a different route. It does not break out from the code execution.

You could also use `else` statement to wrap around the last `next.ServeHTTP(w, r)` which makes it looks cleaner. But Go's idiom tends to use `return` instead of `else`.

Comment: "just redirects the user to a different route" --- that is pretty much inaccurate. https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=58995:59063#L1979 --- it sets headers and response. Basically, it has nothing to do with "routes".